# Can Google Tag Manager help identify the user source of an event?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum. I was told in "SuperUser" that I should move it here.

It is likely to be a very simple question, but I finding a direct answer searching on Google has been difficult.

Will Google Tag Manager automatically record the web page from which an action has been performed and link it to the unique user that performed that action?

What I would like to do, is be able to identify the exact traffic source for email signups on my WP site. Currently I just have the info that someone has signed up, but since the button is in the widget area (sidebar), I have no idea which page they were looking at when they signed up.

I need roughly the same for knowing where my customers come from. Thus what is the traffic source for the conversion.

Is Google Tag Manager the way to go or am I looking into the wrong tool?

Comment: Ok. Then I should leave it here for the moment?

Comment: Let see what happens. I'n not a regular here :/

Answer (score 1):

GA will record the page on which an event took place (you just need to pull in the secondary dimension of Page), but it will not necessarily associate it with the unique user because in order to do so, you will also need to be tracking the user through a custom dimension. So just for the event itself, if you merely want to know the exact traffic source for email signups, then this is possible with GA.

Comment: so I need to set up custom dimensions in order to get this information. Having now, after reading your answer, briefly explored that topic, it seems that I would need to create a sort of "hook" that would be passed to GA... but where from? could I use GTM for this?